# FCM Notification Delivery Report

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

i know after posting message google will send back a message ID and it does not mean that the message was already delivered to the device.

is there anyway to receive delivery reports of sent notifications in FCM?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the `message_id` only identifies that the message was successfully delivered to the FCM servers.

---

[December 17, 2019 - FCM Update](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#december_17_2019)

FCM has removed ongoing support for delivery reciepts via the XMPP protocol. In place of XMPP delivery receipts, developers should [enable delivery data export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#enable-message-delivery-data-export-on-android) in the FCM client SDK.

<s>What I think you're looking for is [Delivery Receipts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#ccs):</s>

> **Delivery Receipt**: If the app server included `delivery_receipt_requested` in the downstream message, the XMPP connection server sends a delivery receipt when it receives confirmation that the device received the message.

Comment: can we get the reports without using xmpp?

Comment: Or do you have an example using xmpp to get delivery receipts?

Comment: @AkshathaSrinivas If its just reports, FCM has [this feature now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42711266/4625829). I haven't had the chance to work on a project that has this requirement yet, so no. Cheers!

Comment: my requirement is, if the notification is not delivered to a device, I want to resend it.

Comment: Not working anymore:(
https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#december_17_2019
December 17, 2019
FCM has removed ongoing support for delivery reciepts via the XMPP protocol. In place of XMPP delivery receipts, developers should enable delivery data export in the FCM client SDK.

Comment: Thanks @Edd. Updated it in.

Comment: In our firebase console, notification reports page is showing no data. We are sending 1000's messages via API. Is there something missing, how to view these metrics in firebase console ?  We have not sent any messages via console.

Comment: Hey @NavinGV. Did you try changing if all filters (date, notification type) still doesn't show any data? It might take a while for _recent_ data to populate. If it still doesn't show up, I suggest reaching out to Firebase Support.

Comment: the logs on https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#enable-message-delivery-data-export-on-android only appear for android tough, my team ended up building completely inhouse monitoring for this.

Answer (score 0):

Method [`projects.androidApps.deliveryData.list`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcmdata/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps.deliveryData/list) reads:

> List aggregate delivery data for the given Android application.

It needs a `parent` node `projects/{project_id}/androidApps/{appId}` passed and then returns:

```
{
  "androidDeliveryData": [
    {
      "appId": "",
      "date": {
        "year": 2021,
        "month": 12,
        "day": 19
      },
      "data": { ... }
    }, ...
}
```

The term "aggregate" rules out individual message delivery reports,

but daily aggregated stats are still better than no stats at all:

[`MessageOutcomePercents`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcmdata/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps.deliveryData/list#messageoutcomepercents):

```
{
  "delivered": number,
  "pending": number,
  "droppedTooManyPendingMessages": number,
  "droppedAppForceStopped": number,
  "droppedDeviceInactive": number
}
```

[`DeliveryPerformancePercents`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcmdata/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps.deliveryData/list#deliveryperformancepercents):

```
{
  "deliveredNoDelay": number,
  "delayedDeviceOffline": number,
  "delayedDeviceDoze": number,
  "delayedMessageThrottled": number,
  "delayedUserStopped": number
}
```

[`MessageInsightPercents`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcmdata/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps.deliveryData/list#messageinsightpercents):

```
{
  "priorityLowered": number
}
```

Those categories are just the same, as one gets posted eg. as Push Kit notification receipt.

---

The SMS standard would also offer message receipts - because these are
 individual messages - and not batches of 500 pub/sub subscribers each.
While this also isn't guaranteed, because one can disable these replies.