# How to see number of recipients for FCM

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I make a request to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` with the following json data:

```
{
    "to": "/topics/push_topic",

    "data" : {
        "language": "tr,en_us",
        "ticker": "...",
        "tickerEnglish": "...",
        "body": "...",
    }
}
```

The response I receive is the following (The message is sent successfully):

```
{
    "message_id": xxxxxxxxxxxxx
}
```

But according to the documentation,  I am supposed to receive a response like the following:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 216,
    "success": 3,
    "failure": 3,
    "canonical_ids": 1,
    "results": [
        { "message_id": "1:0408" },
        { "error": "Unavailable" },
        { "error": "InvalidRegistration" },
        { "message_id": "1:1516" },
        { "message_id": "1:2342", "registration_id": "32" },
        { "error": "NotRegistered"}
     ]
}
```

So, why can't I see success and failure variables in my response? Is that because I send the message to a topic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected response when sending to a [topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging).

The sample response with multiple results is for when you are using the [`registration_ids`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) parameter when sending the message payload.

Comment: @bigO Fairly sure the documentation shows what I stated above. Can you point me to the documentation you were referring to?

Comment: thanks for the answer. So it looks like there is no way to see how many people received the message and how many read it right? I was referring to this part of the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#response

Comment: Not when using topics. If you're using the registration tokens (`to` for single token, `registration_ids` for multiple) when sending the message, you can make use of the [Diagnostics and Statistics page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40341195/4625829) to see if it was successfully sent to the device. For the "*how many read it*" part, I guess you could implement [Delivery Receipts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40110224/4625829).

Comment: Yup. The documentation is referring to use `registration_ids` to get that format of response.