# how to get all device wake up notifications in 3rd party server

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want get wake up notification of my device to my server.
I've android device that when its closed I want my server get notification that message arrived. I dont need the mesage itslef just to know that there is message coming to my device. is it possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM Notification Delivery Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109563/fcm-notification-delivery-report)

Comment: Delivery receipts seems to be the thing you're looking for. The expected flow is, as soon as the client receives the notification, it will send an *ack* like response that your App server could receive.

Comment: I'm asking diffrent thing.. I would like to get indication that message arrived to FCM for the particulat device

Comment: Hi Daniel. Sorry if I misunderstood. Could you edit out your post to provide an idea of the flow of what you were aiming to do? It's still a little confusing.

Comment: Hi, O.K. I will try to be more clear....

Comment: lets take whatsapp as an example.

Comment: lets take whatsapp as an example. I have whatsapp install on my android as well as on my pc as web application.   my understanding is that when message sent to me, it goes first to fcm then send to my mobile device as well as to my web app.  my problematic scenario : if my mobile switched off and message sent to me now, I will not get it in my mobile since its off but I would like get notification to my pc says there is message sent to you. I dont need the message itself.  I wonder if there is an option to register in fcm to get notification for any messsage arrived to me ....  thx